# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un algoritmo en c++ para solicitar de citas en una clínica?

Tags: c++

Necesito crear un algoritmo para la salida de citas en una clínica; donde incluya

- NOMBRES
- APELLIDOS
- DNI
- DIRECCION
- TELEFONO
- SEXO
- FECHANACIMIENTO
- USUARIO

Y dividido por la especialidad que desea el paciente

solo tengo lo que muestro en la imagen, solo deseo que me puedan orientar

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
             #include<stdio.h>

      void re();
      void de();
      void tr();

int numero,usuario,n;
char menu;

struct cliente{
  char nombre[30];
   char apellido[25];
   char DNI[8];
   char Telefono [25];
   char Sexo [1];
   Fechadenacimiento [12;
   int Usuario;
 }
    
 return 0;
}
```

agradecería mucho su apoyo
gracias

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stack overflow, te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para mejorar tus preguntas.
Además, el sitio NO es un lugar donde se hagan tareas. Publica lo que hayas intentado y con eso podemos partir.

Comment: Algunas observaciones: Evita las imágenes a menos que sean muy importantes. Pega tu código en texto para que sea mas fácil copiarlo y replicarlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de la manera mas sencilla, la cual es usar cadenas (o strings).

Debemos tener un flujo de como esta activo nuestro programa, es por eso que haremos lo siguiente:

- Declarar las variables que usaremos (en este ejemplo pondre unas cuantas, a ti te toca complementar)
- Pedir al usuario que ingrese las variables
- Definir la ficha completa del usuario
- Mostrar en pantalla el resultado

Hagamos el primer punto, para ello declaramos las variables que se van a usar:

```
string nombre, apellido, especialidad, nombre_completo;
int telefono;
```

Para este ejemplo necesitaremos esta información, ya que se la pediremos al usuario mediante teclado. Y ese paso es el siguiente en la lista. se obtiene de la siguiente manera:

```
cout << "Ingresa el nombre del paciente" << endl;
cin >> nombre;

cout << "y su apellido" << endl;
cin >> apellido;

cout << "Ingresa el telefono del paciente" << endl;
cin >> telefono;

cout << "A que departamento le toca su cita" << endl;
cin >> especialidad;
```

Ya tenemos lo importante, su nombre, apellido, telefono y a donde será enviado por su cita. Pero, queremos ahorrarnos un poco de trabajo y guardamos el nombre y apellido en la variable `nombre_completo` para mas placer :)

```
nombre_completo = nombre + " " +apellido;
```

Ahora si, estamos listos para imprimir el resultado:

```
cout << "La ficha es: " << nombre_completo << "," << " su numero de teléfono " << telefono << "." << " Y tiene cita con: " << especialidad << endl;
```

Si no funciona lo de arriba, aquí te dejo el código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    //Agregando las variables a usar
    string nombre, apellido, especialidad;
    string nombre_completo;
    int telefono;    
    
    
    cout << "Ingresa el nombre del paciente: "  << endl;
    cin >> nombre;
    
    cout << "Ingresa los apellidos del paciente: " << endl;
    cin >> apellido;

    
    cout << "Ingresa la especialidad de la cita del paciente: " << endl;
    cin >> especialidad;

    cout << "Ingresa el numero de celular del paciente: " << endl;
    cin >> telefono;

    
    nombre_completo = nombre+ " " +apellido;
    cout << "Los datos del paciente son: " << nombre_completo << "," << " su numero de telefono: " << telefono << "y tiene cita con: " << especialidad << endl; 
    
    return 0;
}
```

Con esto ya tienes la base para terminar tu algoritmo :)

Comment: Muchas gracias enserio :")

Comment: Solo recuerda, intenta romper tu problema en pedazo chiquititos para que puedas hacerlo lo mas sencillo posible. Todo esto para que logres comprender cada linea que escribas :) Suerte en tu ejercicio.